# Is it possible to navigate around the circular dependency?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, binary-search-tree, circular-dependency

Strange and potentially stupid question.

As a mini project, I've been working on creating a `Ptr` class to duplicate the mechanism of a pointer - the user should **theoretically be able to use this class just like a real pointer without issue and without needing to interact with "actual" C++ pointers** (besides some obvious syntax changes). The "memory store" is a very large array of characters. I've managed to implement some version of this to a working prototype, but I've been having a lot of trouble in getting this to be useful in creating a data structure - take, the binary search tree.

Say I have a simplified `Ptr` class:

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr
{ 
   Ptr<T>(){}
   T _a_item;
};
```

and a simplified `tree_node` struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct tree_node
{
    T _item;
    Ptr<tree_node<T> > _left;
    Ptr<tree_node<T> > _right;
};
```

I'm guessing you immediately spot the glaring problem of the circular dependency, which prevents compilation. Normally, the `tree_node` struct would look like:

```
template <typename T>
struct tree_node
{
    T _item;
    tree_node<T>* _left;
    tree_node<T>* _right;
};
```

which would be perfectly fine. The problem is that my `Ptr` class is not an actual pointer.

I've looked around various forums, and I'm pretty sure what I'm asking for is impossible. But I did want to make sure anyways: is there any way I can make this work without forcing the user to use "real" pointers? **I'd also be happy to hear any restructuring tips that could help me make a BST using a self-created `Ptr` class.**

Edit: Link to exact compilation error: https://godbolt.org/z/rhh15xYK8

Comment: No, I don't spot any problems that prevent compilation (other than perhaps that `Ptr`s constructor is private). The code shown [compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/PEGnEqjes) for me.

Comment: Sorry, this is my bad! forgot a variable in the Ptr class - here's the new link: https://godbolt.org/z/rhh15xYK8. I'll edit the post above.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The ptr class contains an element instead of a pointer. So the tree node would require infinite size as not only tree node needs to contain a copy of itself, it needs to contain two copies of itself.

Comment: @ALX32z I had a feeling that was true. Do you have any restructuring tips that could potentially lead to being able to create a BST using a self-created Ptr class? Or is it an impossible task?

Comment: Just make the `Ptr` contain a pointer instead of a copy.

Comment: Store all the nodes in an array and use indices instead of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not circular dependency but the fact that your `Ptr` class contains an element instead of a pointer. So your `tree_node` needs to contain inside two whole copies of itself! That it is not technically possible.

To make the code make sense and compile you just need to make `Ptr` into an actual wrapper of a pointer instead of a wrapper of a copy.

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr
{ 
    public:
    Ptr<T>(){}
    T* _a_item;
};
```

No you cannot sensibly avoid using pointers - nor I see any point in it. You could replace pointers with indices inside a global array - but that would only complicate things. It would be just pointers with extra steps.

Comment: Seems like the motivation is to use this as a learning exercise on how to make a user-defined C++ type act like a built-in C++ type (as much as possible)